# coordinates of perpendicular line segment in 2d Cartesian space

Tags: matlab, math

I'm having surprisingly difficult time to figure out something which appears so simple. I have two known coordinates on a graph, (X1,Y1) and (X2,Y2). What I'm trying to identify are the coordinates for (X3,Y3).

I thought of using sin and cos but once I get here my brain stops working. I know that

```
sin O = y/R
cos O = x/R
```

so I thought of simply importing in the length of the line (in this case it was 2) and use the angles which are known. Seems very simple but for the life of me, my brain won't wrap around this.

[image]

The reason I need this is because I'm trying to print a line onto an image using poly2mask in matlab. The code has to work in the 2D space as I will be building movies using the line.

```
X1 = [134 134 135 147 153 153 167]
Y1 = [183 180 178 173 164 152 143]

X2 = [133 133 133 135 138 143 147]
Y2 = [203 200 197 189 185 173 163]

YZdist = 2;

for aa = 1:length(X2)
     XYdis(aa) = sqrt((x2(aa)-x1(aa))^2 + (Y2(aa)-Y1(aa))^2);

     X3(aa) = X1(aa) * tan(XYdis/YZdis);
     Y3(aa) = Y1(aa) * tan(XYdis/YZdis);

end
polmask = poly2mask([Xdata X3],[Ydata Y3],50,50);
```

Comment: sorry, let me add in code. This is actually going to be integrated into a program for later

Comment: Please label which line has length 2. Also, this is not the right forum for pure math problems. Try https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The point is that you have two unknowns and therore need two simultaneous equations to find them. One is length and the other is slope, which is based on the angle. Two perpendicular segments will have slopes `m` and `-1/m`.

Comment: I've edited your title. While the intuition of using angles is fundamentally correct, I don't think your approach is going to work as-is

Comment: I originally used the arctan to back calculate an angle and then used it help extend my lines on a graph. I used the atan2d function in matlab. I figured I would do something similar but this is where I ran into the problem. Let me update the question some more

Comment: The only really missing piece of info is which segment has length 2. I'm guessing x2-x3 because if you don't know that length directly or indirectly, there are infinite valid solutions.

Comment: You are right. the (X2,Y2)--(X3,Y3) length is 2. I know the majority of the information, for instance, the X1 Y1 and the distance between points 1 and 2. I also know the angles as the points are perpendicular to line points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one approach would be to first construct a vector `l` connection points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`, rotate this vector 90 degrees clockwise and add it to the point `(x2,y2)`.

Thus `l=(x2-x1, y2-y1)`, its rotated version is `l'=(y2-y1,x1-x2)` and therefore the point of interest `P=(x2, y2) + f*(y2-y1,x1-x2)`, where `f` is the desired scaling factor. If the lengths are supposed to be the same, then `f=1` and thus `P=(x2 + y2-y1, y2 + x1-x2)`.

Comment: This is a much more intuitive approach than solving the two equations I suggested in the comments directly. The rotation encapsulates the slope equation while the scaling factor `f` is a function of the desired length, so all the information is used. Very neat +1

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion